# Apache James Undeliverable Email

Tags: java, email, james

Is there a way to have Apache James send an undeliverable email to a default email of some sort if the address is undeliverable for whatever reason? If storing the mail folders in a database, having some other sort of mechanism for collecting undeliverable email would be even better, but I assume having a n email bounced back is my most likely bet. Am I missing a configuration option of some sort? I am using James 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link http://wiki.apache.org/james/HelpOnConfiguration/EmailSupport
Create a general mail id and configure mail_from
This value is used for the "From:" header in the emails sent, if no better value is known.
So if the user replies it comes back to this generic email box.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem. I can successfully send mail from a user, but if the to address is not a real email, it does not send an undeliverable email back to that users inbox. Not sure if this is something built into James, or if its something I have to handle on my own.

Comment: Please check this notes http://wiki.apache.org/james/JamesDocumentationNotes       Why does it take 30 hours to get a bounce message?
Check also this link http://james.apache.org/server/archive/configuration_v2_0.html

Comment: So in 30 hours I should receive a message in the users inbox stating it was undeliverable?

Comment: It states "If it is a permanent error (like no user or mailbox is full), then the bounce will come back immediately." Doesn't this mean the bounce back should happen immediately?

Comment: I think what you do is to just let bounces come back to whomever the sender is, that's standard.  Why would you want to change that default behavior?

Comment: Vijetha is right, it just takes 30 hours to get the bounce back, but James is in fact set up to bounce undeliverable emails automatically.